# Appveyor $(configuration) macro doesn't work

Tags: deployment, macros, yaml, appveyor

I am trying to setup appveyor github deployment. So i have this in my appveyor.yml

```
 branches:
    only:
      - master
 configuration:
  - Release

 after_build:
  7z a C:\projects\ezlng\$(configuration)\ezlng-$(configuration)-v$(appveyor_build_version).zip C:\projects\ezlng\$(configuration)\*.*

 deploy:
  release: ezlng-$(configuration)-v$(appveyor_build_version)
  provider: GitHub
  artifact: C:\projects\ezlng\$(configuration)\ezlng-$(configuration)-v$(appveyor_build_version).zip
  auth_token:
    secure: uWdKAZIK2m90nx8z7s0yVGAKoZtKJb55zi47O2Wntf3EvRLE6H70GtCzcSIu8iE8
  draft: false
  prerelease: false
  on:
    branch: master
```

As you see i want to pack binaries to the zip archive. I added $(configuration) macro to the path of file but it doesn't expands to the name of configuration. 
I am getting this error from 7z
`C:\projects\ezlng\$(configuration)\:  WARNING: The system cannot find the path specified`
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Put `7z` parameters into quotes to extrapolate string:

```
7z a "C:\projects\ezlng\$(configuration)\ezlng-$(configuration)-v$(appveyor_build_version).zip" "C:\projects\ezlng\$(configuration)\*.*"
```